# Unable to find a matching SQL Class on drupal 8 drush command in Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I get this error when i run sql-connect --debug

C:\Devdesktop\public_html>drush sql-connect --debug
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.18-commandfiles-0-cad2978683eacbb2b6166a982f0652f5 [0.12 sec, 3.03 MB]                        [debug]

Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.41 sec, 7.7 MB]                                                                     [bootstrap]

Bootstrap to phase -1. [0.41 sec, 7.71 MB]                                                                   [bootstrap]

Found command: sql-connect (commandfile=sql) [0.41 sec, 7.71 MB]                                             [bootstrap]

Calling hook drush_sql_connect [0.42 sec, 7.97 MB]                                                               [debug]

Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.45 sec, 8.81 MB]                                          [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 8.6.7 root directory at C:\Devdesktop\public_html [0.47 sec, 8.82[bootstrap]
MB]

Find command files for phase 1 (max=3) [0.47 sec, 7.62 MB]                                                       [debug]

Cache HIT cid: 8.1.18-commandfiles-1-4d681924793d846935eee95c1410194c [0.48 sec, 7.62 MB]                        [debug]

Cache HIT cid: 8.1.18-annotationfiles-1-67c3b884213a861fb5d13d03d098f389 [0.48 sec, 7.7 MB]                      [debug]

Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.54 sec, 8.33 MB]                                          [bootstrap]

Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.54 sec, 8.33 MB]                                         [bootstrap]

Find command files for phase 2 (max=3) [0.56 sec, 8.33 MB]                                                       [debug]

Cache MISS cid: 8.1.18-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.57 sec, 8.33 MB]                      [debug]

Cache HIT cid: 8.1.18-commandfiles-2-922fe8da44dce18f081805a74eb1725e [0.57 sec, 8.33 MB]                        [debug]

Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.58 sec, 8.49 MB]                                 [bootstrap]

Create from request [0.58 sec, 8.51 MB]                                                                          [debug]

add service modifier [0.6 sec, 9.07 MB]                                                                          [debug]

Find command files for phase 3 (max=3) [0.6 sec, 9.08 MB]                                                        [debug]

Drush\Sql\SqlException: Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your database connection          [error]

details. in C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\sql\sql.drush.inc:549
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\sql\sql.drush.inc(221):

drush_sql_get_class()

## 1 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(422): drush_sql_connect()

## 2 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(231):

_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)

## 3 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(199): drush_command()

## 4 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Boot\BaseBoot.php(67):

drush_dispatch(Array)

## 5 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\preflight.inc(66):

Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()

## 6 C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(12): drush_main()

## 7 {main} [0.6 sec, 9.1 MB]

Command dispatch complete [0.6 sec, 9.04 MB]                                                                    [notice]